# Implemented AppCompat library not found in my own android library dependency

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-library

I have created **xten-framework** Android dependency library into maven repository with dependency implementation of appcompat, RecyclerView and design library. It working well, no any issue when I build and run it using module project in dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.xtensolutions.country:country-sdk:1.0.1'
    implementation project(':xten-framework')
}
```

After deployed on maven repository, I have removed **implementation project(':xten-framework')** from dependency and added **implementation 'com.xtensolution.support:xten-framework:1.0.0'** in **build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/myusername/maven/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.xtensolutions.country:country-sdk:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.xtensolution.support:xten-framework:1.0.0'
}
```

When I compile my project, I got the error that package  **android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity** not exists

I can't understand, why support appcomapat package not found in my own library, when other created class is found of my library. where I am going to mistake to developed a library project with appcompat support? what I miss to add?

I am very thankful if anyone will give me the right solution to resolved this issue

Comment: Have you tried to add   "implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'" library ?

Comment: yes, i already added "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1" as dependency in my library project, but still getting error

Answer (score 0):

In your library, if you're using the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
}
```

When you using the library for your another project, the project won't see
the `support:appcompat` because it is not exposed to your project. So, you need to add the `support:appcompat` to your app module.

Or use `api` instead of `implementation` in your library, like the following:

```
dependencies {
     api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
}
```

Comment: I have also try with 'api' instead of 'implementation' but still same issue.

Comment: this is quite strange. `api` is working like `compile`, what is happened when you're using `compile`?